# How to get FileInfo via a foreach Loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, asp.net-2.0, code-conversion

Trying to convert some VB to C#... (learning C#, too).
I have some code that loops through files in a directory and retrieves their file information.  I have this originally in VB, but am trying to learn C#, and the online convertors don't give me code that will pass .net 2.0.

Here is the error:
`Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement`

Here is the code I have:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
FileInfo[] files = null;
files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

FileInfo f = default(FileInfo);
foreach (f in files) {  ...
}
```

I tried putting `foreach(FileInfo f...`   but it gives me a different error:
    `A local variable named 'f' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'f', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

How do I fix it?

Comment: `foreach (FileInfo f in files)` should work; what error do you get?

Comment: Added the error to the question.  Sorry.  I thought that should work too, but this is .net2, not .net4 - maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Just remove `FileInfo f = default(FileInfo);` because you don't need to initialize iteration variable.

Comment: No, your problem is that you are allready using the variabl ename `f` somewhere else in the function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
FileInfo[] files = null;
files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

// I removed the declaration of f here to prevent the name collision.
foreach (FileInfo f in files)
{  ...
}
```

Here is a simpler version of the code:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
foreach (FileInfo f in dirInfo.GetFiles())
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I just updated my question to reflect the error I recieve when using that.

Comment: Re-read the answer now. I have updated it to make it more clear.

Comment: That was it!  I'll mark this as accepted in 4 more minutes.  Thanks a bushel.  I know I have to read some basics (I know it in VB, but I don't want to translate everything to C#...), but I don't have time to study right now. You all are so helpful!

Comment: Why assign `null` to array of files?

Comment: I tried to avoid modifying the code too much, to keep the OP from becoming confused.

Comment: I don't know about null, but I know that it does what it did in VB code.  If not null, what else would be assigned?  It is an aspx page, and doesn't know the filelisting until page_load or a submit.

Comment: Thanks again!  I put that in my page.  It looks like that avoids setting `files` to null, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide type of variable used inside loop. In your case it will be `FileInfo`. But with C# 3.0 or later you can just write `var` and compiler will infer type for you:

```
foreach (FileInfo f in files) 
{  
   // ...
}
```

Read more about foreach statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Complete solution (you don't need to initialize iteration variable and array of files):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) 
{
   // use file  
}
```

Comment: I have to run this under a sharepoint application, hence .net 2.0.  using `var` gives up this error:  `The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's where it looks like you're going wrong:

```
FileInfo f = default(FileInfo);
foreach (f in files) {  ...
}
```

You are defining f outside of the loop, and then attempting to define it within the loop.

If you need the default to be f, try this:

```
FileInfo f = default(FileInfo);
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
         relevant code here
    }
```

Otherwise delete the statement declaring the variable "f"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
        FileInfo[] files = null;
        files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo f in files)
        {
        }
```

Edit:

This would be cleaner, in  my opinion:

```
        foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo(currentDir).GetFiles())
            {
            }
```

Comment: Why assign `null` to array of files?